# How to use reference of a reference in Offset function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have column titles that refer to column titles in another sheet, i.e. in the cell `Summary!A1` I have the formula `=sales!B1`.

I want to get data from the cell `sales!B2` into the cell `Summary!A2` so that if I change the value in the cell `Summary!A1` to `sales!C1` it will automatically get me data from the cell `sales!C2`.

I tried the following formula in the cell `Summary!A2`:

```
=offset(indirect(Summary!A1),1,0)
```

but I end up with `#REF` error.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this you may change this as per offset function

In Sheet1      A1   is sales  (name of the sheet you want to refer
               B1   is A1     (Cell reference in the above sheet
in C1 this formula

```
=INDIRECT("'" &A1 & "'!"&B1)
```

The answer will change as you change the value in A1 & B1
Regards

Comment: Yep, this works. Not exactly what I wanted, but will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First the problem. 
 In excel, the inside of a cell is not visible to other cells. Meaning if I have a 7 in A1, and =2+5 in B1, c1 can not tell any difference when use in its formula.

So there are two things that you are trying to do with A1. Get the data from the Sales sheet And also change the reference point for the A2 cell. A cell is a single bucket, and except for some weird pretzel cases, each cell can only do or hold 1 thing.

We need to do each action in a separate manor.  Need the help of another cell that will be used to select the data source.  For this example, $e$1 holds a value of 1,2,3 where 1=B, 2=C,3=D etc.

then the formula becomes

- =OFFSET(Sales!$A$1,ROW()-1,$E$1)

there is no need for using indirect with this approach.

To use indirect, then will need to use the name manager because the Ref error occurs referring to another sheet with a not fully named source cell. 
For this example $f$1 contains a B, or C, etc. to use as the column name. In name manger give this cell a name like X then the formula becomes

- =OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sales!$" & x  & "$1"),ROW()-1,0)

This prevents the Ref problem and works similar to original question intent.
or this could be improved by naming INDIRECT("Sales!$" & x  & "$1") as SData.
The formula becomes

- =OFFSET(SData,ROW()-1,0)

Instead of indirect in the name manager, going to cell A1 on Sales could be directly named as Sdata and it would not impact anything.